# Activate feature in Preferences and add tab dynamically

Tags: android

My main activity initially has 4 tabs, which I add using this code:

```
    mMainPagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mMainPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Now the user can activate a feature in the Preferences:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).edit().putBoolean(FEATURE_ENABLED, true).apply();
```

Once the user has selected this option and goes back to the main activity, **an additional tab** must be added to the TabLayout. This action cannot be undone by the user (the new tab will remain forever and cannot be removed again). What is the best way to do that? Right now, I override the `onResume` method in main activity and do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int currentNumOfTabs = mMainPagerAdapter.getCount();
    boolean featureEnabled = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(SettingsFragment.FEATURE_ENABLED, false);
    if (featureEnabled && currentNumOfTabs == 4) {
        mMainPagerAdapter.setNumOfTabs(5);
        mMainPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that this is not the correct approach. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I register a preference changed event and update the adapter:

```
private void registerEnabler() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    mListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            if (key.equals(SettingsFragment.FEATURE_ENABLED) && prefs.getBoolean(SettingsFragment.FEATURE_ENABLED, false)) {
                mMainPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateTabIcons();
            }
        }
    };

    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);
}
```